# R data samples counting

Tags: r, data.table, sample

I have a task to do using R. I need to make 10000 samples of a vector of 12 elements each of them between 1 and 7. I did this using:

```
dataSet = t(replicate(10000, sample(1:7, 12, r=T)))
```

Now I need to count the rows of this dataSet that contain all the values from 1:7.

How can I do that and is there a better way to represent the data than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be (you need to use `set.seed` in order to make this reproducible)

```
indx <- 1:7
sum(apply(dataSet, 1, function(x) all(indx %in% x)))
## 2336
```